# Does anyone know of any good tutorials for the Slick 2D lib?

Tags: java, graphics, applet, 2d

There is a 2D java graphics library called Slick 2D (http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) that seems to be used by a bunch of indie games (mostly applets), but the documentation is a little lacking.  Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this lib?

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely check out their forums, and ask questions.  They've been very helpful to me in the past.